# How to find successive numbers in a List<int> with duplicates?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I was bored so I decided to try & make a Yahtzee game of my own, same exact rules as the actual game, just wanted to test my programming skills on this (which aren't amazing as of yet).

The code posted below is being used to check for straights (both Small & Large).
I'm sure you can see for yourself, but just in case you don't, it works like this:

All 5 dice's values are placed in a List, which are then sorted using the `List<T>.Sort()` method.

Now they should be sorted in the list, in ascending order (for example 1,2,3,4,5).

In order to find out if it's a large straight, I simply use an int which adds 1 to it's value if a small straight is detected, a large straight is then found due to my "Large Straight = Small Straight * 2" logic, which may be flawed, but it seems to make sense to me :) .

This works, but not always, as you can probably see, this code won't work if I have duplicate values somewhere in the middle, for example 1,2,3,3,4,6. This series of numbers should still give me a small straight, but it won't.

Now as for my actual question: How do I modify this code so it'll always detect both small & large straights?

```
List<int> valList = new List<int>();
foreach (Dice d in dList)
{
    valList.Add(d.Value);
}
valList.Sort();

txtSmall.Text = "0";
txtLarge.Text = "0";
int straight = 0;
if (valList[0] == valList[1] - 1 && valList[1] == valList[2] - 1 && valList[2] == valList[3] - 1)
    straight++;
if (valList[1] == valList[2] - 1 && valList[2] == valList[3] - 1 && valList[3] == valList[4] - 1)
    straight++;
switch (straight)
{
    case 1:
        if (txtSmall.IsEnabled)
            txtSmall.Text = "30";
        break;
    case 2:
        if (txtSmall.IsEnabled)
            txtSmall.Text = "30";
        if (txtLarge.IsEnabled)
            txtLarge.Text = "40";
        break;
}
```

PS: Just in case you need to know how I have my `Dice` class, here it is (even though I can't see why you would have need of it):

```
class Dice
{
    private static CryptoRandom r = new CryptoRandom();
    public static int uBound = 1;
    public static int lBound = 7;
    public string Path { get; set; }
    private int value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }
    private bool locked;
    public bool Locked
    {
        get { return locked; }
    }

    public Dice(int lowerBound = 1, int upperBound = 6)
    {
        uBound = upperBound + 1;
        lBound = lowerBound;
        this.Roll();
        this.locked = false;
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        this.value = r.Next(lBound, uBound);
    }

    public void Lock()
    {
        this.locked = true;
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        this.locked = false;
    }
}
```

PPS: If there's a better way to detect these things, feel free to share, however try to answer my question as well :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is not an issue and I understand the problem correctly I would try something like this:

```
var count = dList.Count; //6
var straights = dList.Select(dice => dice.Value)
    .Distinct() //5,3,1,6,4
    .OrderBy(dice => dice.Value) //1,3,4,5,6
    .Select(dice => dice.Value + (count--)) //7,8,8,8,8
    .GroupBy(n => n) //[7,{7}],[8,{8,8,8,8}]
    .OrderByDecending(group => group.Count());

var longestStraight = straights.First().Count(); //4
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about what you mean by `dice => dice.Value`, care to elaborate?

The reason I ask is because I just tried this code & all I get is an error saying: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: Oh sorry.. I though your `valList` was of type `List<Dice>`. Nevermind, just get rid of the `dice => dice.Value`

Comment: Just tried that & didn't work either :P I do have a List<Dice> though, I'll try it out on that instead ;)

Comment: I didn't test the code, so there might be some errors, but the logic should work.

Comment: Managed to get it to work using this code: [Code](http://pastebin.com/DGREeG4R) It seems to work, however I just got a sequence {3,4,5,5,5} & for some reason it still thought it was a small straight (4 in a row). I didn't check your logic for validity as your code is using things that I haven't used before and I don't think I know how to use them better than you do. :)

Comment: can you explain which straights you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70606/discussion-between-alexey-adamsky-and-yorrick).

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way is to just invoke [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before you sort it, which removes all duplicates:

```
List<int> allDice = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
IEnumerable<int> uniqueDice = allDice.Distinct();
IEnumerable<int> sortedDice = uniqueDice.Sort(x => x);

//etc.
```

Otherwise, your methodology is reasonable. Nothing comes quickly to mind as a better way to find a small straight.

Comment: `The uniqueDice.Sort(...)` seems not to work: `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Sort' and no extension method 'Sort' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Am I missing something or did you forget to add something? :P

Never mind, I simply sorted the `List<int>` before calling the `Distinct()` method, seems to work fine now :)

Comment: Small issue I just found, with this method, I can't properly check for straights anymore. As my above code checks for Lists with 5 items in it, which means if suddenly it checks a list with 4 items, it stops working. I can't really seem to be able to figure out the loop which I could use to make this work though >.>

Comment: @Yorrick instead of hard-coding your indices, use a `for` loop against the `Count` method of `sortedDice`

Comment: I did, however I couldn't find the right way for checking everything without going out of bounds (for example: `for (int i = 0; i<list.Count();i++) { if (list[i] == list[i+1] - 1) { ... } }` would eventually go out of bounds.

Comment: @Yorrick Doing it that way you do have to be very careful with the bounds (since you are indexing i+1). There *are* loops to do it, you could even ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, just for fun:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines if the dice passed in contain a strait
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dice">The dice to test</param>
/// <returns>0 if there are no straits, 1 if there is a small strait, 
/// or 2 if it contains both a large and small strait</returns>
private static int ContainsStrait(IEnumerable<int> dice)
{
    var uniqueDice = dice.Distinct().ToList();
    if (uniqueDice.Count < 4) return 0;

    uniqueDice.Sort();

    int consecutiveNumbers = 1;
    int lastValue = -1;

    foreach (var uniqueDie in uniqueDice)
    {
        if (uniqueDie == lastValue + 1)
        {
            consecutiveNumbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            consecutiveNumbers = 1;
        }

        lastValue = uniqueDie;
    }

    return (consecutiveNumbers > 4) ? 2 : (consecutiveNumbers > 3) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

To test it:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var rolls = new List<List<int>>
    {
        {new List<int> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}},
        {new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}},
        {new List<int> {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2}},
        {new List<int> {3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6}},
        {new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2}},
        {new List<int> {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
    };

    foreach (var roll in rolls)
    {
        int result = ContainsStrait(roll);

        Console.WriteLine("The roll: {0} does {1}contain a small strait {2} a large strait",
            string.Join(", ", roll),
            result > 0 ? "" : "not ",
            result == 2 ? "and" : result == 1 ? "but not" : "or");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the dices in an array?

```
  int Sum = 0;
  int[] i = new int[5];
```

Problem here is, if we have doubles, we must move them to the end of the array.

```
  Array.Sort(i);
    for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
  {
    int temp = 0;
    if( i[j] == i[j+1] )
    {
      temp = i[j];

      for( int k = j; k < 4; k++ )
      {
        i[k] = i[k+1];
      }

      i[4] = temp;
    }
  }
```

When that is done, it's simply a matter of evaluation

```
if( ((i[0] == 1) && (i[1] == 2) && (i[2] == 3) && (i[3] == 4)) ||
  ((i[0] == 2) && (i[1] == 3) && (i[2] == 4) && (i[3] == 5)) ||
  ((i[0] == 3) && (i[1] == 4) && (i[2] == 5) && (i[3] == 6)) ||
  ((i[1] == 1) && (i[2] == 2) && (i[3] == 3) && (i[4] == 4)) ||
  ((i[1] == 2) && (i[2] == 3) && (i[3] == 4) && (i[4] == 5)) ||
  ((i[1] == 3) && (i[2] == 4) && (i[3] == 5) && (i[4] == 6)) )
{
 Sum = 30;
}
```

And for a large straight, it's even easier :

```
Array.Sort(i)
if( (i[0]+1 == i[1]) && (i[0]+2 == i[2]) && (i[0]+3 == i[3]) && (i[0]+4 == i[4]) )
{
Sum = 40;
}
```